# How to handle double quotes in JSON value?

Tags: python, json, double-quotes

I have string that I receive as a HTTP response. Unfortunately, the string is quite in a raw format and I am unable to convert it to the JSON object.

Example string:

```
json_string = '{"client_id":8888,"time":null,"questions":{"id":10000,"answered":"true","answer":"The "project" was good, I enjoyed it. Do you plan to repeat it?"},"other":"When is the "project" released?"}'
```

The problem with the string is that it contains double quotes in some of the values (user answers). The keys of the values that can contain double quotes are not always the same (here "answer" and "other" may be different in other responses). The user answer can contain any characters (commas, brackets, double quotes, ...).

I tried to use different loaders (json, yaml) and I even tried to parse the string by myself with regexp, but I have always failed.

Is there any way how to convert this string to JSON object?

Comment: What is *creating* that string? From a JSON perspective, it's broken.

Comment: You mention that the string you receive is from an HTTP response. However, it is not in valid JSON format. Does the server you are communicating intend for it to be parsed as json?

Comment: The string is created by an external application (developer), so I don't know how is the string built. However, according to the documentation, the response should be JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be clear, the correct solution here would be to fix whatever is sending that HTTP response; the proper way to include double quotation marks in a JSON string is to backslash them:

```
{ "key": "value with \"double quotes\" inside" }
```

Any JSON parser should accept the above as a valid object.

You can't reliably parse something with unescaped quotes because you can't tell which ones are the actual string delimiters and which ones are enclosed data. If you can assume that the quotes are balanced (so there's always an even number of quotation marks inside any string) then you could construct a parser to transform it into the right syntax, but it's not going to be a simple regex-based fix.

That said, with your sample data, it looks like the embedded quotes are surrounded by spaces, and the actual delimiter quotes aren't. So you could try running it through a replace of  `"` (space-quote) with  `\"` (space-backslash-quote) and `"`  (quote-space) with `\"`  (backslash-quote-space) and see if that works.

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately, I can't escape "double quotes with spaces", because some of the user's answers could contain double quotes at the end of the sentecnce. I will try to speak to the developer if there is any chance to send the response with escaped quotes. Thank you